# My .qgz project file is empty, how to recover?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgz

I'm using QGIS 3.24 and after opening .qgz project file there's **no layers, no basemap.**

The only error is " Cannot unzip file 'Y:/(...)name.qgz'

I'm using Windows 10.

Also there's no .qgz~ file in the folder.

Comment: restore the file from your last backup

Answer (score 7):

How big is the file? If its zero bytes (or anything smaller than a few hundred) then that file doesn't contain the data any more.

If it looks big enough, then, since a .QGZ file is a ZIP file with a different name, rename it to .ZIP and see if any ZIP recovery utilities work on it. You might get something.

Otherwise, restore it from your most recent backup. If you are using cloud-based storage (Google Drive, Box etc) they may have kept older versions.

Comment: Thank you, there was older version saved, I didn't noticed since I was in panic.